# ionic build failed:multiple dex files define landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/accessibilityserviceinfocompatics

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When I added cordova plugin camera,the build.gradle changed.

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
  // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
  debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
  releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
  compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
  // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

Then I run **ionic build android**,I am suddenly getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.                            
DexException: Multiple dex files define 
Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice                            
/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

What should I do to resolve this problem? Please help me. Thank you!